# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] while trying to login with wrong password

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

As backend for react, I have `node v16.13.0` and `express 4.17.2` and  this express route for login

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
     try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      !user && res.status(404).json("user not found");
  
      const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)

      !validPassword && res.status(400).json("wrong password")
  
      res.status(200).json(user)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err)
    }
  });
```

It works fine when the credentials are correct, but when the password is wrong I get:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2022:14:50:33 +0000] "POST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 500 16
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/me/Desktop/myapp/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:776:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/me/Desktop/myapp/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/me/Desktop/myapp/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at /home/me/Desktop/myapp/api/routes/auth.js:49:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm wondering what is wrong here and how can i fix it?

Comment: Your Javascript code has syntax errors, please check.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Sorry I removed an extra `if` which was a typo.

Comment: Still syntax errors. I suspect that `res.status(400).json("wrong password")` and `res.status(200).json(user)` are *both* executed, that gives the error.

Comment: Well I turned it to `if (!validPassword) { res.status(400).json("wrong password") } ` but still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

when you pass the wrong credentials the `res.json` will be called twice and the error says that.

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
     try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      if(!user) {
         return res.status(404).json("user not found");
      }
  
      const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)

      if(!validPassword) {
        return res.status(400).json("wrong password")
      } 
  
      res.status(200).json(user)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Right this resolved the error. But can you explain why replacing `!user && ..;` with  `if(!user) { ...` solves the problem? I thought They are logically the same.

Comment: this is one of my best practices when handling logic for each response call of express,
so if I need to skip the next lines and just respond I will use a return before `res`

Comment: @MBH if you try to use the `return` keyword with the ternary operators (the one you were using: `!user && ...;`) you will be unable to put the `return` keyword along with it, which resolved your error. But through if-else that can be done as shown in the answer.

Comment: @DaniyalMalik your comment is unintelligble to me. Maybe needs som grammatical revision.